# Removing carriage return and tab escape sequences from string in Bash

Tags: bash, tr

Assume I have this string:

```
Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r
```

how can I remove the characters "\n, \t, \r". The string literally looks like that, it does not contain tabs or new lines. They are only characters.

When I try

```
echo "Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r" | tr -d '\t'
```

tr assumes I am trying to remove tabs, so it doesn't work and prints examtly the same string. Any ideas about how to remove them? I have the same problem with sed.

Thanks

Comment: Add option `-e` to `echo` or use `sed` to search and replace.

Comment: Err. Those aren't "raw" tabs or newline characters, then, those are tab and newline escape sequences. Raw characters would be literal tabs or newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r" | sed -E 's,\\t|\\r|\\n,,g'
Your name isBobbyBlahck
```

or

```
$ echo "Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r" | sed -e 's,\\[trn],,g'
Your name isBobbyBlahck
```

`-E` is on OS X; replace it with `-r` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the string does not have any tab characters in it.  It has a backslash followed `t` but no tabs:

```
$ echo "Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r" | tr -d '\t'
Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r
```

This string has a tab in it and `tr` removes it:

```
$ echo $'Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r'
Your name is
Bobby   Blahck
$ echo $'Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r' | tr -d '\t'
Your name is
BobbyBlahck
```

If you want special characters in bash string, use `$'...' to create them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a character group to check what's following the '\':

```
echo "Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r" | sed -r 's/\\[nrt]/ /g'
```

Answer (score -1):

`sed -e 's/[\\\][t]//g' -e 's/[\\\][n]//g' -e 's/[\\\][r]//g'`

another answer too

`sed -e 's/\\[[a-z]]*//g'`

Comment: This is pointlessly complicated.  `[t]` is exactly the same as `t` and `[\\\]` is exactly the same as \\. Your answer is equivalent to `sed -e 's/\\t//g' -e 's/\\n//g' -e 's/\\r//g'`

Comment: @authprivate, did _you_ try Ewan's solution? Works perfectly. `sed -e 's/\\t//g' -e 's/\\n//g' -e 's/\\r//g' <<<'Your name is\nBobby\tBlahck\r\r'` behaves as-desired, thus making the "pointlessly complicated" claim beyond dispute.

Comment: @authprivate, something doesn't have to be nonfunctional to be a bad answer. It can, for instance, be needlessly complicated and difficult to read; that makes it bad too. Fortunately, that's easy to fix -- the "edit" button is right there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy edited bro .. but what i mean it works so no need to down vote u can give me notes and appreciate ur efforts thanks

Comment: Edit not showing up here -- which is a problem; SO actually won't allow a vote to be retracted without an edit after a given period of time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for you ... great sense and manners is enough .. up vote for u .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80232/discussion-between-auth-private-and-charles-duffy).